# Multiple HLOOKUP summation and being able accounting for "" in one of the results

Tags: excel

I have a matrix setup where I am using multiple HLOOKUPS in a cell to derive a result.  Due to some of the source data having blank cells, the HLOOKUP results in a #VALUE! error if any of the results lookup on a blank cell.  I cannot use the IFERROR function because that will negate the addition and result in the entire formula deriving a blank result when in reality a summation of numbers should result (but because of the occurence of even one blank instance, the formula does not work).  The way the spreadsheet is setup, I cannot change the source data to have zero in the blank cells, even though this would essentially solve the issue in a different way.  Please see the example:

(HLOOKUP(L$1&"zzz.",Formula!$1:$34,$T5,FALSE)+HLOOKUP(L$1&"yyy",Formula!$1:$34,$T5,FALSE)+HLOOKUP(L$1&"uuu",Formula!$1:$34,$T5,FALSE)+HLOOKUP(L$1&"ppp",Formula!$1:$34,$T5,FALSE)+HLOOKUP(L$1&"ccc",Formula!$1:$34,$T5,FALSE)+HLOOKUP(L$1&"ddd",Formula!$1:$34,$T5,FALSE)

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you use `IFERROR(HLOOKUP(...),0)+IFERROR(HLOOKUP(...),0)+...`? If I understand your issue correctly, I think that would work.

Comment: Great idea but even if I put the IFERROR into each formula, I obtain the same error.  What happens is the one formula (with the 'ppp' quotes) that is linking to the blank cell on another worksheet returns a value even if the (IFERROR,0) logic is used.

Comment: You get an error because you are trying to do maths with some text values, you can get round that, in general by using SUM function, e.g instead of =HLOOKUP1+HLOOKUP2 you use =SUM(HLOOKUP1,HLOOKUP2) - note the commas between the HLOOKUPS - with that syntax any text values are ignored - .....but you would still get an #N/A error if any of the lookup values don't appear. XOR LX's solution will fix that too so it's the way to go if lookup values don't repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula can be re-written in a different and more efficient way, viz:

=SUM(SUMIF(Formula!$1:$1,L$1&{"zzz.","yyy","uuu","ppp","ccc","ddd"},INDEX(Formula!$1:$34,$T5,)))

which also has the benefit that any search values which are not found do not cause the formula to error.

Even better would be to put those six search strings in the actual worksheet somewhere, e.g. A1:A6, in which case the above becomes the even-more succinct:

=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(Formula!$1:$1,L$1&$A$1:$A$6,INDEX(Formula!$1:$34,$T5,)))

Regards